# jQuery - Making every even number in a paragraph bold

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a puzzle in jQuery. I found out how to generate random numbers, but now I want to iterate over these numbers and make them bold if the number is even.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    var countNumbers = Number($("input[type=number]").val());
    for (var i = 0; i < countNumbers; i++) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000);
        $("#numbers").text($("#numbers").text() + rand + " ");
    }

    var numbers = $("#numbers").text().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        if (Number(numbers[i]) % 2 === 0) {
            numbers[i] = "<span class='bold'>" + numbers[i] + "</span>";
        }
    }
    $("#numbers").html(numbers.join(' '));
});
```

It seems like the `bold` class is not getting added to any of the elements. Any ideas why it's not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/rL3y28cm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to  change for loop condition to `i < numbers.length`, use **[`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)** property to get array size

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var countNumbers = Number($("input[type=number]").val());
  for (var i = 0; i < countNumbers; i++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000);
    $("#numbers").text($("#numbers").text() + rand + " ");
  }

  var numbers = $("#numbers").text().split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    //------------------------^-----------
    if (Number(numbers[i]) % 2 === 0) {
      numbers[i] = "<span class='bold'>" + numbers[i] + "</span>";
    }
  }
  $("#numbers").html(numbers.join(' '));
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" />
<button>Generate Numbers</button>
<p id="numbers"></p>
```

**Update :**  You can reduce your code and make it more simple

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var countNumbers = Number($("input[type=number]").val());
  var res = [];
  // array for storing the random number
  for (var i = 0; i < countNumbers; i++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000);
    // generating random number
    res.push(rand % 2 == 0 ? "<span class='bold'>" + rand + "</span>" : rand);
    // checking even or odd and wrapping by span if needed finally  pushing the string to array
  }
  $("#numbers").html(res.join(' '));
  // joining the array value and set it as html
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" />
<button>Generate Numbers</button>
<p id="numbers"></p>
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that one. Today might just be one of those days for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier and more performant to generate the random number, add the span, collect all numbers (with bold or not) into a string, and apply them at once to the HTML:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var countNumbers = Number($("input[type=number]").val());
  var randStr = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < countNumbers; i++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000);
    randStr += (rand % 2 === 0 ? "<span class='bold'>" + rand + "</span>" : rand) + ' ';
  }

  $("#numbers").html(randStr);
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" />

<button>Generate Numbers</button>

<p id="numbers"></p>
```